TypeScript can no longer check the existence of properties correctly as soon as checks are outsourced to a function?
I use the following type as property for my component:
type MapProps = {
    standalone: true
} | {
    standalone: false
    inContextOf: Nullable<Artifact | ExcavationSite>
    fieldSetter: UseFormSetValue<FieldValue<any>>

}

Further down, the following checks are performed:
if ((props.standalone || !props.standalone && !props.inContextOf) || props.inContextOf && !IsEntityArtifact(props.inContextOf))
                return;


if (props.inContextOf?.Latitude == 0.0 && props.inContextOf.Longitude == 0.0)
                return;


            const newPoint = {
                type: "Feature",
                geometry: {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: [props.inContextOf!.Longitude, props.inContextOf!.Latitude]
                }
            };


Everything is working as expected with this implementation, however as soon as i move those checks to a function like this
const CheckReturnScenarios = (): boolean => {

        if ((props.standalone || !props.standalone && !props.inContextOf) || props.inContextOf && !IsEntityArtifact(props.inContextOf))
            return true;


        if (props.inContextOf?.Latitude == 0.0 && props.inContextOf.Longitude == 0.0)
            return true;

        return false;
    };

and I use it like this
    if (CheckReturnScenarios())
                return;

            const newPoint = {
                type: "Feature",
                geometry: {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: [props.inContextOf!.Longitude, props.inContextOf!.Latitude]
                }
            };

I do get the following error: TS2339: Property inContextOf does not exist on type MapProps Property inContextOf does not exist on type { standalone: true; }
I'm wondering why it's suddenly no longer possible for TypeScript to determine that the properties being accessed must exist here, because otherwise the check performed above would abort the function.
Would be nice if someone could shed some light on this.
Thank you!
Edit:
The entire component where the error occurs:
import { FC, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

type Person = {
  Name: string;
  Age: number;
  Kind: number;
};

type Product = {
  Title: string;
  Description: string;
  Kind: number;
};

type ComponentProps =
  | {
      standalone: true;
    }
  | {
      standalone: false;
      inContextOf: Nullable<Person | Product>;
      fieldSetter: Function;
    };

export const MyTestComponent: FC<ComponentProps> = (props) => {
  //#region Constants

  //#endregion

  //#region States

  //#endregion

  //#region Hooks
  useEffect(() => {
    Initialize();
  }, []);
  //#endregion

  //#region Functions

  const CheckAbortScenarios = (): boolean => {
    if (
      props.standalone ||
      (!props.standalone && !props.inContextOf) ||
      (props.inContextOf && !IsEntityPerson(props.inContextOf))
    )
      return true;

    if (props.inContextOf?.Kind == 0.0) return true;

    return false;
  };

  function IsEntityPerson(entity: Person | Product): entity is Person {
    return (entity as Person).Name !== undefined;
  }

  const Initialize = (): void => {
    if (CheckAbortScenarios()) return;

    /*The error happens here*/
    const kind = props.inContextOf!.Kind;
  };
  //#endregion

  //#region Render

  return <div></div>;

  //#endregion
};



return type of the function is boolean so typescript no longer does any type narrowing based on the logic within the function, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#example/assertion-functions for how you may wish to make your function narrow the type yourself

Does this answer your question? user defined type guards [typescript]

Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] suitable for copying and pasting into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing. Right now this is an excerpt of code and missing definitions, so it's not complete (and merely adding more code would probably make this not minimal).  This is quite possibly something which will just start working in TS5.5 (as long as you don't explicitly annotate boolean as the return, which would break it). But without a [mre] I can easily test, I'm speculating.

@jcalz I added two sample projects to the question.

@TadhgMcDonald-Jensen If I have understood this correctly, type guards only apply within the block for which they are checked, but assertions also apply to the rest of the control flow, right?
How would I then proceed with my sample, since I have a discriminated union as a property, would I have to define both types separately in order to be able to tell the assertion function which one it is or can I do it differently?

Thanks for the update, but external links aren't sufficient here; we can't ask people to leave SO to see the example code. A [mre] should be plaintext in the question itself. It should be minimal: meaning a single text file (not multiple with imports, unless your issue is with importing) with only what's necessary to demonstrate the issue. The idea is that someone should be able to ctrl-c ctrl-v into any old TS IDE and get to work on it. A link to a web IDE is a nice supplement. But it doesn't count as a [mre]. Could you [edit] to provide one?

@jcalz I've now added the code of the whole component which can be copy pasted into an IDE to see the error.

Thanks. For your code as written it's not possible, see ms/TS#9998. Your function narrows a closed-over variable, but TS cannot accurately track control flow narrowing across function boundaries. The closest you can get is to make your function a custom type guard function, but that would require you input the variable to the function. I'd show how, but I see you've already got an answer below to that effect. Let me know if you want my answer anyway.

@jcalz sure, I'd like to see your answer too!

Since you're moving the type checking logic to a separate function, you're looking for the type guarding is operator.
In the code that you showed at the bottom you are already using it for the IsEntityPerson() function.

Revisiting your ComponentProps type, we should first separate each case in the union into separate types. I actually would go as far as replacing Nullable<Person | Product> logic into another union where inContextOf could be null or Person | Product, as such:
type SubTypeA = {
  standalone: true
}
type SubTypeB = {
  standalone: false
  inContextOf: null
  fieldSetter: Function
}
type SubTypeC = {
  standalone: false
  inContextOf: Person | Product
  fieldSetter: Function
}

type ComponentProps = SubTypeA | SubTypeB | SubTypeC

Now, your type guard function should receive the variable that needs type checking as an argument and its return type should be a argument is MyType. This basically discrimates argument into the type MyType if the function's return is true, otherwise it turns into Exclude<typeof argument, MyType>.
Given this, you should probably separate this type guard into two functions:
const CheckSubtypeA = (props: ComponentProps): props is SubTypeA => {
  return props.standalone
}
const CheckSubtypeB = (props: ComponentProps): props is SubTypeB => {
  return (
    CheckSubtypeA(props) ||
    (!props.standalone && !props.inContextOf) ||
    (props.inContextOf && !IsEntityPerson(props.inContextOf)) ||
    props.inContextOf?.Kind == 0.0
  )
}

And finally, inside your Initialize function:
const Initialize = (): void => {
  if (CheckSubtypeA(props) || CheckSubtypeB(props)) return

  const kind = props.inContextOf.Kind // no longer errors and no need for a null assert (!)
}


Thanks for the detailed example! What I don't get is, when should I use the type guards and when assertion functions? For me they seem to do the same, but I'm sure I'm missing something here

They're both pretty much the same. The obvious use case would be to use the function variant when you need to separate the discrimination logic for reusing purposes (or for easier unit testing too). By offloading this logic to another function, your Initialize function would be much simpler. Though it pretty much depends on your personal preference and needs.
